# How can I escape sqlite3 query parameters in bash?

Tags: bash, sqlite, sql-injection

I have a script that boils down to this right now:

```
#!/bin/bash

SEARCH_PARAM="$1"
SQLITE3_DB="$2"

# Don't inject me please :(
sqlite3 "$SQLITE3_DB" "SELECT foo FROM Bar WHERE bundleId='$SEARCH_PARAM';"
```

A glaring problem is that the `$SEARCH_PARAM` value is very vulnerable to SQL injection. Can I fix that from the bash script or do I need to drop in another scripting language, like Python, to get access to query parameters?

[How can I escape characters in SQLite via bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766207/how-can-i-escape-characters-in-sqlite-via-bash-shell) is similar but it has fixed string arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL strings, the only character that needs escaping is the single quote, which must be doubled.

This can be done by using pattern substitution in the parameter expansion:

```
sqlite3 "..." "... bundleId = '${SEARCH_PARAM//\'/\'\'}';"
```

(Non-standard SQL implementations like MySQL might have additional characters that need escaping.)

Comment: It seems to be somewhat specific to SQLite that only quotes need to be escaped, not a universal truth of SQL implementations; at least for one, MySQL also allows escapes with backslashes, and it means that backslashes have to be escaped too. (The SQLite manual does seem to confirm that quotes are the only characters that have to be escaped, at least.)

Comment: That only replaces the first occurrence of a single quote.

Comment: I'm getting the correct result with `" ... bundleId = '${SEARCH_PARAM//\'/''}'"`.

Comment: The backslash is a MySQL extension; it has no special meaning in standard SQL.

Comment: I understand that it's not standard SQL, but I'm not aware of any SQL implementation that is nothing more than standard SQL. SQLite deviates from standard SQL in many regards, too. It looks like your answer could apply to both SQLite and MySQL (and Oracle and SQL Server and Postgre and MariaDB) because it talks about "standard SQL", but implementation deviations make it dangerous on some RDBMS. I'm sure that there's a way to phrase your answer in a way that makes it unambiguous that it might not be sufficient for *all* SQL implementations, but that it's enough for SQLite.